# Internet sensitive UI with http call in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, connection, stream-builder

I'm trying to pop up an alert dialog box when user turn off the internet connection once he/she already in the app.
When I start the application without internet connection, it successfully showing the "No Internet" alert box. But when I turn it ON again it doesn't redirect to my desire Page.

```dart
void main() async{
      runApp(MyApp());
    } 
    
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          theme: ThemeData(
            primaryColor: AppColor.colorPrimary1,
            accentColor: AppColor.colorPrimary2,
          ),
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          title: 'Hola',
            home: ForInternetChecking(),
                 routes: {
                      '/SplashScreen': (_) => SplashScreen(),
                      '/LoginAtFirst': (_) => LoginAtFirst(),
                      ..................
```

Now, initialy if I turn off the internet it successfully showing the the alertBox, but It should also redirect to my `SplashScreen()` when I turn on my internet again. its showing up error in my console

> Tried to send a platform message to Flutter, but FlutterJNI was detached from native C++. Could not send. Channel: plugins.flutter.io/connectivity_status. Response ID: 0

```
class ForInternetChecking extends StatefulWidget {
  // const ForInternetChecking({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ForInternetCheckingState createState() => _ForInternetCheckingState();
}

class _ForInternetCheckingState extends State<ForInternetChecking> {
ConnectivityResult previous;
  @override

  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    try {
      InternetAddress.lookup('google.com').then((result){
        if(result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty){
          //internet conn available
          Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => 
            SplashScreen(),
          ));
        }else{
          // no conn
          _showdialog();
        }
      }).catchError((error){
        // no conn
        _showdialog();
      });
    } on SocketException catch (_){
      // no internet
      _showdialog();
    }


    Connectivity().onConnectivityChanged.listen((ConnectivityResult connresult){
      if(connresult == ConnectivityResult.none){

      }else if(previous == ConnectivityResult.none){
        // internet conn
        Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => 
            SplashScreen(),
          ));
      }

      previous = connresult;
    });




  }


  

      void _showdialog(){
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
        title: Text('ERROR'),
        content: Text("No Internet Detected."),
        actions: <Widget>[
          ElevatedButton(
            // method to exit application programitacally
            onPressed: () => SystemChannels.platform.invokeMethod('SystemNavigator.pop'),
            child: Text("Exit"),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      barrierDismissible: false
    );
  }



  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            CircularProgressIndicator(),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                top: 20.0
              ),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "Checking Your Internet Connection."
                  ),
          //          ElevatedButton(
          //   // method to exit application programitacally
          //   onPressed: () => SystemNavigator.pop(),
          //   child: Text("Exit"),
          // ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );

  }
```

And also  I'm trying to pop up the alert box when user turn of the Internet when already using it.

```
     Future<bool> checkinternet() async {
    try {
      final result = await InternetAddress.lookup('google.com');
      if (result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty) {
        return Future.value(true);
      }
    } on SocketException catch (_) {
      return Future.value(false);
    }
    throw Exception(e);
  }
```

Variables in my state class

```
StreamSubscription? connectivitySubscription;
 ConnectivityResult ?_previousResult;
 bool dialogshown = false;

    @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    connectivitySubscription = Connectivity().onConnectivityChanged.listen((ConnectivityResult connresult) {
      if (connresult == ConnectivityResult.none) {
        dialogshown = true;
         showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
        title: Text('ERROR'),
        content: Text("No Internet Detected."),
        actions: <Widget>[
          ElevatedButton(
            // method to exit application programitacally
            onPressed: () => SystemChannels.platform.invokeMethod('Systemnavigator.pop'),
            child: Text("Exit"),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
      } else if (_previousResult == ConnectivityResult.none) {
        checkinternet().then((result) {
          if (result == true) {
            if (dialogshown == true) {
              dialogshown = false;
              Navigator.pop(context);
            }
          }
        });
      }

      _previousResult = connresult;
    });

  }

   @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();

    connectivitySubscription!.cancel();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Its absolutely work.. Its just doesn't work in low end mobile ..

YT tutorial for [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C1kFZlyaWKs&t=263s)